# Facebook | Youtube embed video not showing on friends news feed but showing on my profile page, Fb.ui

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am using "fb.ui share dialog" to share video from app to my wall, resulting not embedding on friends news feed, message is showing but no video.

Where as i can see video embed on my profile page, with message. All working fine but not on friends wall.

See screenshot
[image]
[image]

Code

```
FB.ui(
       {
         method: 'feed',
         name: 'Lorem ispm',
         link: 'google.com',
         picture: 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+ getParameter(addressValue, 'v') +'/0.jpg',
         caption: 'Hello',
         source: 'http://www.youtube.com/v/'+ getParameter(addressValue, 'v') +'?version=3&autohide=1&autoplay=1',

         type: 'video',
         description: 'Hello'
       },
       function(response) {
         if (response && response.post_id) {
           //alert('Post was published.');
         } else {
           //alert('Post was not published.');
         }
       }
     );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the `link` parameter as the youtube video url. You dont need to use `image` and other parameters.

```
FB.ui(
   {
     method: 'feed',
     name: 'Lorem ispm',
     caption: 'Hello',
     link: 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='+ getParameter(addressValue, 'v'),
     description: 'Hello'
   },
   function(response) {
     if (response && response.post_id) {
       //alert('Post was published.');
     } else {
       //alert('Post was not published.');
     }
   }
 );
```

[Example](https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?%20%20app_id=145634995501895%20%20&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption%20%20%20&link=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1G4isv_Fylg&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

Youtube has their `og tags` defined on their page. It will provide facebook with the related `image` and other things.

---

Another thing to note is that- you must use [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) now instead, the [feed dialogs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.0) are deprecated.

Comment: Can you pls show an example of above usage with share dialog